# Google Cloud Scheduler Permissions to call API

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I need to allow Cloud Scheduler to call a REST endpoint in an App Engine app in the same project. I have set the scheduler target to "App Engine HTTP" and put the correct service and path to the API. When I test access to it, I am receiving a 401 Unauthorized. This occurs due to the presence of the OpenAPI cloud endpoints service on the API. I have service accounts listed in my OpenAPI yaml that are permitted to access the API, but I am not sure how to allow the Cloud Scheduler through. I have not found any documentation so far that provides this information.

Comment: Have you had a chance to review this article?

https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth

Does it answer the question?

Comment: @Kolban I have looked through this. It refers to making a general HTTP call, rather than targeting App Engine. My endpoint uses OAuth2, and I get this error message when I attempt to set it up.
"A URL must start with "https://", and host must end with ".googleapis.com" for a job with an OAuth authorization header"